# Chequers MiniMax Confusion (Java)

Tags: java, minimax

[Here is the link to my whole Chequers Java code.](https://www.sendspace.com/file/j1rnek)

I'm writing a chequers game with a MiniMax algorithm as the AI. It all works fine as I manually move chequers (player vs. player) but whenever I call the MiniMax method, I encounter a null pointer error.

This is because when I call 'MultiJump', at some point it tries to move a Chequer that is not there anymore. The code tries to move a Chequer from [2][2], which has already been moved recursively as the child nodes are created. I can't find where or why it is doing this - as I go through the debugging process the correct multi-jump moves are made, but rather than exiting when in the right place, this null pointer error is thrown.

It would be great if someone could take a look at my code and let me know if they can find why the algorithm is trying to move something it has already moved.

Please don't hesitate to let me know if there's anything I can help with or anything I can answer to help you help me :)

Below I'll copy & paste the MiniMax method & the MultiJump method. Again, see the top of the post for my whole code.

My MiniMax control method is:

```
public double miniMax(String side, int depth, PlaySpace board)
{
    this.board = board;
    this.side = side;
    this.depth = depth;
    double a = 0;

    if(depth==0){
        a = evaluateState(board);
        return a;
    }

    if (side.equals("A")){
        a = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for(ChequersMove move : board.getLegalMoves(side)){ 

            PlaySpace child = new PlaySpace(board.returnState());
            child.setState(board.returnState());

            for(int x=0;x<move.multiJumpCount(board,move,side,0);x++){ 
                child.moveChequer(move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnCurrentX(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnCurrentY(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnDestX(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnDestY());
            }

            Tree tree = new Tree();
            double eval = tree.miniMax("B",depth-1,child);
            if(eval > a){
                System.out.println(eval);
                a = eval;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    if(side.equals("B")){
        a = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for(ChequersMove move : board.getLegalMoves(side)){ through all of the possible resulting moves
            PlaySpace child = new PlaySpace(board.returnState()); 
            child.setState(board.returnState());
            for(int x=0;x<move.multiJumpCount(board,move,side,0);x++){
                child.moveChequer(move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnCurrentX(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnCurrentY(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnDestX(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnDestY());
            }
            Tree tree = new Tree();
            double eval = tree.miniMax("A",depth-1,child);
            if(eval > a){
                a = eval;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

My MultiJump Method is:

```
ChequersMove[] multiJump(PlaySpace board, ChequersMove move, String side, int jumpCount)
{

    jumpPath.addElement(move);

    if(move.isJump()==true){
        PlaySpace child = new PlaySpace(board.returnState());
        child.setState(board.returnState());
        child.moveChequer(move.returnCurrentX(),move.returnCurrentY(),move.returnDestX(),move.returnDestY());
        jumpCount++;

        if(child.getLegalMoves(side)!=null){
            for(ChequersMove path : child.getLegalMoves(side)){
                if(path.returnCurrentX() == move.returnDestX() && path.returnCurrentY() == move.returnDestY() && path.isJump() == true){
                    multiJump(child,path,side,jumpCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    multiJump = new ChequersMove[jumpPath.size()];

    System.out.println("MultiJump length = " + multiJump.length);

    for(int i = 0; i < jumpPath.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        multiJump[i] = (ChequersMove)jumpPath.elementAt(i);
    }

    return multiJump; 

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct: `child.moveChequer(move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnCurrentX(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnCurrentY(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnDestX(),move.multiJump(board,move,side,0)[x].returnDestY());
`? I'd expect a single call `someObj = move.multiJump(board,move,side,0);`, using `someObj` as needed thereafter.

Comment: Please try to provide a more detailed error description. Only staunch enthusiasts will sift through 30k uncommented source.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for answering so swiftly! In this game of Chequers, if you can take, you have to take & you can make multiple chained jumps in one 'move'. The purpose of this line is to allow for the multiple chained jumps to be taken without tripping up the game's logic constrictions. MultiJump returns an array of moves, which all need to be moved on the board before returning the next state (the next game board in the MiniMax tree). -- Really sorry but I'm not sure what someObj is / how i could use it to improve my code. Again thanks!

Comment: `someObj` would be a supporting variable to contain the list of moves. As its stands, your code generates the same move list for each of the 4 move coordinates involved (from X/Y, to X/Y). Aside from being grossly inefficient, I suspect that your move generator does not handle the repeated calls to generate the very same move array correctly ( I must admit though that I haven't looked into the generator,so it's just a hunch ).